# Why let word added to servlet,applet,cmdlet?

Tags: history, conceptual

Myself a history buff.I love to find out nuances behind naming.As a java developer we have come across ***servlet(Server side java component),applet(client side java component with gui),portlet(similar to servlet in portal environment)***.Now in Powershell also they have **cmdlet** or **commandlet**.My question is about why these are suffixed with **let** and what is the generic semantic meaning of this **let**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the English language some words can get the suffix *"-let"* to express that something is small, e.g. *"chainlet"* (for a small chain) or *"arrowlet"* (for a small arrow), see [the list of *"English words suffixed with -let"*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-let) on *wiktionary.org*. So I think the *"let"* in all the words mentioned by you was added to express that the corresponding component is small or lightweight, e.g. an Applet is a small computer program/component. However, I am not a native speaker of the English language.

On [this page](https://github.com/mide42/ListOfLets/blob/master/ListOfLets.md) you'll find a list of further names for software components suffixed with *"-lets"* based on Java technology (e.g. Batchlets and Doclets) and also non-Java technology (e.g. Dashlets or Droplets).

Comment: *"let"* is a so called *"diminutive suffix"*.

Comment: Kubelet, Servlet, etc...